# Do I need to file Form 8990 if my partnership has Box 20 Code AE?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, schedule-k-1

The [partner's instructions for Schedule K-1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1065sk1.pdf) states the following:

> Code AE. Excess taxable income. If the partnership was required to
> file Form 8990, it may determine it has excess taxable income. Report
> the amount of excess taxable income on Form 8990, Schedule A, line 43,
> column (f), if you are required to file Form 8990. See the
> Instructions for Form 8990 for additional information.

However, the Instructions for form 8990 does not explicitly state whether a partnership being required to file Form 8990 means an individual partner must file Form 8990.

**Is there a way to determine whether an individual partner is required to file Form 8990, given Code AE in Box 20 of the Schedule K-1?**